# Javascript - Como adicionar coisas no html e salvar informações do html

Tags: javascript

Se o título do tópico ficou confuso peço desculpas, porque não sei como eu faria a minha pergunta de forma resumida e correta, mas é o seguinte...

Estou na reta final de um curso de informatica (acaba dia 13 desse mês) e a última tarefa do curso é criar um app para celular usando html, css e javascript e por fim fazer o porte para celular usando o Phonegap

O problema é que o curso não ensina JS (ensina apenas html e css) e eu estou com muita dificuldade em aprender JS, além da data de entrega estar muito próxima, a ideia do meu app é criar listas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme esta na imagem, preciso fazer uma função para que quando eu clique no botão "Adicionar Item" na página seja adicionado outra caixa (um retangulo com input e textarea dentro dele) igual as duas que estão abaixo do input para adicionar titulo a lista

Sou muito leigo com JS, assisti várias vídeo aulas para tentar aprender, mas ainda não consegui entender nem a sintaxe básica direito

O que eu gostaria de saber é: o que eu deveria focar em aprender especificamente de JS, para fazer o botão "Adicionar Item" funcionar da forma que eu descrevi, e como eu faria para que as caixas criadas e as informações digitadas pelo cliente nos inputs e textarea salvem

Desde já peço desculpas pela minha leguisse no assunto

Meu HTML (somente o da pagina da imagem)

```js
let currentItem = 3;
function adicionarItem(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // evitar que o form seja submetido

// criar o input
let input = document.createElement('input');
with (input) {
    classList.add('titulo');
    placeholder = 'Digite o Título da lista';
    maxLength = 19;
}
// criar o textarea
let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
with (textarea) {
    classList.add('descricao');
    cols = 5;
    rows = 5;
    maxLength = 130;
}

// adiciona ambos em um div
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'retangulo' + currentItem; // usa o contador como parte do id
div.appendChild(input);
div.appendChild(textarea);

// atualiza o contador (assim o próximo div não terá id repetido)
currentItem++;

// adiciona a div no form
document.querySelector('#formulario').appendChild(div);
}

// ao clicar no botão, adiciona um novo item
document.querySelector('#botaoNovoItem').addEventListener('click', adicionarItem);
```

```css
body {}

div {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.botao {
  background: #00FFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 300;
  font-size: 50;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 1px #131;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.botao:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #131, inset 3px 3px 3px #131;
  transform: translate (3px, 3px);
}

.botaor {
  background: #836FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 300;
  font-size: 50;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 1px #131;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  outline: 0;
}

.botaor:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #131, inset 3px 3px 3px #131;
  transform: translate (3px, 3px);
}

.listas {
  font-size: 50;
  text-align: center
}

.loading {
  font-size: 50;
  text-align: center
}

.logo {
  width: 856;
  height: 502;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.titulo {
  width: 300;
  height: 45;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 28;
}

#retangulo {
  width: 300;
  height: 200;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: black;
  background: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 280;
  height: 45;
  margin-top: 5;
  font-size: 25;
}

.descricao {
  width: 290;
  height: 140;
  margin-top: 9;
  font-size: 20;
}

.adicionaritem {
  margin-left: 400;
  background: #00BFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 1px #131;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 15;
  width: 100;
}

.adicionaritem:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #131, inset 3px 3px 3px #131;
  transform: translate (3px, 3px);
}

.voltar {
  margin-left: 400;
  background: #00BFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 1px #131;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 15;
  width: 100;
}

.voltar:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #131, inset 3px 3px 3px #131;
  transform: translate (3px, 3px);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title> Criar Lista </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personalizacao.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src= "javascript.js"> </script> 
  </head>

                                   <body>
                                   
                                 
                                   
                        <a href="2-Tela Inicial.html"> <button class="voltar"> ⬅ Voltar para o início  </button></p> </a>
                        
                        <input type="text" class="titulo" placeholder="Digite o Título da lista" maxlength=18>
                        
                        
                        <form id="formulario">
  <button id="botaoNovoItem" class="adicionaritem">Adicionar item</button>
  <div id="retangulo1">
<input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Novo item" maxlength=19> 
<textarea class="descricao"  cols="5" rows="5" maxlength=130></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="retangulo2"> 
<input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Novo item" maxlength=19> 
<textarea class="descricao"  cols="5" rows="5" maxlength=130></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
                        
                
                        
                        
                        
                    
                          
  
                                    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para adicionar um novo item, você pode dar uma pesquisada na função `appendChild` se for JavaScript puro, ou `append` se você estiver usando jQuery. Tem um exemplo bem bacana em português [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282406/append-javascript).

E para pegar os dados dos campos, você pode a função `getElementById` ou `getElementsByTagName` juntamente com a propriedade `value`, que também está no link do exemplo anterior.

Espero ter ajudado e boa sorte com o trabalho.

Comment: Agradeço pela dica, salvei o site aqui, certamente vou usa-ló, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

A ideia básica é usar [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) para criar os novos campos e adicioná-los em algum elemento já existente.

Tem outros detalhes para arrumar, como por exemplo:

- [um `id` deve ser único na página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), mas você criou dois `div`'s com o mesmo `id`. Isso não dá erro (no sentido de não carregar a página), mas ao buscar ou manipular esses elementos, o JavaScript não se comportará da maneira esperada (pois as funções que usam o `id` assumem que ele é único)
- o HTML está mal formado (tem tags que fecham sem a respectiva abertura, as `div`'s não têm o fechamento, etc). Então eu eliminei algumas partes no exemplo abaixo, e deixei somente o essencial para o exemplo (depois você completa com o restante do seu código)

Também eliminei boa parte do CSS, já que é somente "visual" e não interfere no JavaScript (pois a ideia é focar no funcionamento deste, então depois você adiciona novamente seu CSS).

Coloquei as `div`'s dentro de um `form`, pois entendo que a ideia seja submeter estes dados posteriormente (se for só para preencher e não fazer nada, me pareceria inútil), então estes elementos deveriam estar em um `form`. Aproveitei para deixar este `form` como o elemento no qual serão adicionadas as novas `div`'s.

```js
let currentItem = 3;
function adicionarItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // evitar que o form seja submetido

    // criar o input
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    with (input) {
        classList.add('titulo');
        placeholder = 'Digite o Título da lista';
        maxLength = 19;
    }
    // criar o textarea
    let textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    with (textarea) {
        classList.add('descricao');
        cols = 5;
        rows = 5;
        maxLength = 130;
    }

    // adiciona ambos em um div
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'retangulo' + currentItem; // usa o contador como parte do id
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(textarea);

    // atualiza o contador (assim o próximo div não terá id repetido)
    currentItem++;

    // adiciona a div no form
    document.querySelector('#formulario').appendChild(div);
}

// ao clicar no botão, adiciona um novo item
document.querySelector('#botaoNovoItem').addEventListener('click', adicionarItem);
```

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <button id="botaoNovoItem" class="adicionaritem">Adicionar item</button>
  <div id="retangulo1">
    <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Novo item" maxlength=19> 
    <textarea class="descricao"  cols="5" rows="5" maxlength=130></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="retangulo2"> 
    <input type="text" class="item" placeholder="Novo item" maxlength=19> 
    <textarea class="descricao"  cols="5" rows="5" maxlength=130></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, alterei o código do meu html conforme o código que vc mandou e adicionei o JS, porem o botão "Adicionar Item" não funcionou, olhando no Console apareceu a seguinte mensagem de erro  " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at  javascript.js:35". Revisei o código para ver se eu conseguia encontrar o erro mas não consegui, vou atualizar a pergunta com o código de agora, se conseguir me apontar aonde eu errei seria de grande ajuda.

Comment: Atualização: percebi pela visualização aqui do fórum que ao invés de estar adicionando as textareas e os inputs que preciso, esta criando inputs novos do titulo, estranhamente ao testar no Google Chrome nem isso cria